# TBB Intel Threading Building Blocks for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: build, arm, raspberry-pi, tbb, raspberry-pi3

So I am trying to compile Intel's TBB C++ library which enables parallelisms in programs. I am particularly needing this to use C++ React, which is a library which provides reactive library (e.g. asynchronous loops) for a project I am doing.

I have figured out how to compile it for Raspberry Pi 2. But my problem is that the guides I have seen have only updated for the ARM-7a architecture.

Currently, when I try to make a build which uses TBB as a dependency, I get this error:

```
In file included from /home/pi/tbb43_20150611oss/include/tbb/tbb_machine.h:247:0,
             from /home/pi/tbb43_20150611oss/include/tbb/task.h:25,
             from /home/pi/tbb43_20150611oss/include/tbb/task_group.h:24,
             from /home/pi/cpp.react-master/include/react/engine/PulsecountEngine.h:18,
             from /home/pi/cpp.react-master/src/engine/PulsecountEngine.cpp:7:
/home/pi/tbb43_20150611oss/include/tbb/machine/gcc_armv7.h:31:2: error: #error compilation requires an ARMv7-a architecture.
 #error compilation requires an ARMv7-a architecture.
```

I just want to know how I can port TBB to work on ARM-53 for the new Raspberry Pi.

An easy solution such as replacing _ARM_ARCH_7A_ in gcc_arm7.h would be nice, but how do people go about porting TBB for other architectures?

Thank you

Comment: Isn't the Pi 3 still running the exact same ARMv6 userspace as all the others? If you've successfully built it for the Pi 2, that ought to work just fine on the 3 - for userspace code the differences between ARMv7 and 32-bit ARMv8 are mostly negligible anyway.

Comment: How would I go about porting the code for Pi 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest update August 2018,

Check out my git: https://github.com/abhiTronix/TBB_Raspberry_pi

**Latest binary  (2018 - Update 4) of TBB for the Raspberry Pi  exclusively for Raspberry Pi (.deb) file**
compiled for a Raspberry Pi 2/3 Model B/B+ running Raspbian Stretch.

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to contribute to TBB (e.g. to port it for some other architecture), you can go to ["submit contribution"](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/submit-contribution) page on the [open source site](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) and send your patch.

To port TBB on ARMv8, you have at least several options:

- If ARMv8 and ARMv7 are very similar, you can try to extend the check on line 30 in gcc_arm7.h to work with ARMv8;
- If ARMv8 and ARMv7 are quite different, you can create gcc_arm8.h (or gcc_arm with support v7 and v8) and improve the logic in tbb_machine.h near lines 246-248;
- Theoretically, if gcc on ARMv8 supports built-in atomics, you can use gcc_generic.h on ARMv8 (see tbb_machine.h:249)

It looks like that you do not need to improve make files but I'd recommend running `make test` to be sure that modified TBB works correctly on your system.

**[UPDATE] TBB has been ported to ARMv8 since version [2018 U5](https://github.com/01org/tbb/blob/tbb_2019/CHANGES#L85).**

Comment: I was already aware of this. I was trying to get specific information regarding how comparable ARMv7 code is to ARM 53 (which doesn't seem like its exactly a type of ARM-v8 processor from what I can tell). Again, do you know if gcc on ARMv8 supports built-in atomics? I know version 6.1 was just released, but I do not know how to look up this information (I can't really find it in the gcc documentation)

Comment: To tell the truth, I know almost nothing about ARM architecture. I hope someone from ARM community will join this thread. So I can only suggest you trying gcc_arm7.h and/or gcc_generic.h on your architecture. If it compiles successfully (or you will be able to fix the issues), run the tests to make sure that everything is Ok.